# Use AsyncTask and fill TextViews, Buttons with the results

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, textview

I have a question for you. It seems that there are similar questions around but didn;t work for me. I use an AsynkTask to parse a JSON odject and then i want  to feed some components like TextViews and Buttons with the results. Although i spent hours testing examples i can't get it to work.
At first i did the parsing inside doInBackground():

```
public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // do stuff before posting data
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String postResponse = "";
            try {
                // url where the data will be posted
                String postReceiverUrl = "http://server.com/Json/consumer.php";
                Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConsumerID", "52"));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                // Convert response to String
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                // TEST
                //postResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON Object
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                // Get the JSONArray "Consumer"
                JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("Consumer");
                //List<String> detailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Creating the array that will hold the json items
                String[] info = new String[ja.length()];
                // Loop through all fields
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("userid");
                    String fname = c.getString("userfullname");
                    String tel1 = c.getString("tel1");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String county = c.getString("county");
                    String country = c.getString("country");
                    String rpoints = c.getString("RedeemPoints");
                    String level = c.getString("Level");
                    // Add JSON object into the ArrayList
                    //detailsList.add(name);
                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.v(TAG, "User ID: " + id + "\n"+ "Username: "+ fname + "\n"+ "Redeem points: "+rpoints);
                }

                //Log.v(TAG, "Testing response: " +  postResponse);


            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return postResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String postResponse) {
            // do stuff after posting data
            if (postResponse.isEmpty() || postResponse.equals(ERROR_RESPONSE) ) {
                //listener.onFailedLogin(postResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Response is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Got results!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //name.setText(fname);

            }
        }
    }
```

Which didn't work so i tried do the parsing in the onPostExecute() as shown in [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/asynctask-android-example/) again with no luck...:

```
public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            // do stuff before posting data
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "";
            try {
                // url where the data will be posted
                String postReceiverUrl = "http://server.com/Json/consumer.php";
                Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConsumerID", "52"));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                // Convert response to String
                postResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();


                //Log.v(TAG, "Testing response: " +  postResponse);


            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return postResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // do stuff after posting data
            if (postResponse.isEmpty() || postResponse.equals(ERROR_RESPONSE) ) {
                //listener.onFailedLogin(postResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Response is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Got results!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TEST
                //postResponse = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON Object
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                    // Get the JSONArray "Consumer"
                    JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("Consumer");
                    //List<String> detailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    // Creating the array that will hold the json items
                    String[] info = new String[ja.length()];
                    // Loop through all fields
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString("userid");
                        String fname = c.getString("userfullname");
                        String tel1 = c.getString("tel1");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String county = c.getString("county");
                        String country = c.getString("country");
                        String rpoints = c.getString("RedeemPoints");
                        String level = c.getString("Level");
                        name.setText(fname);
                        // Add JSON object into the ArrayList
                        //detailsList.add(name);
                        // show the values in our logcat
                        Log.v(TAG, "User ID: " + id + "\n"+ "Username: "+ fname + "\n"+ "Redeem points: "+rpoints);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not understand. What is unworking? Did you check parse and downloading json? Is it correct? Or it is correct, but truble in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: do you get any caught exception?

Comment: Kirill everything works ok except form the TextViews... I really don't know why i cannot set the text...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. You need to use "publishProgress" and the actualization must be performed in onProgressUpdate.